# Copy folder from a local server with PHP

Tags: php, cmd

I can copy the files contained in a folder located on a local server to my pc as follows:

```
 C:\Users\Dell>net use "\\192.168.2.3\Archivos" 
 /user:"user" "password" /persistent:no

 C:\Users\Dell>xcopy "\\192.168.2.3\Archivos" 
 "C:\Users\Dell\Documents\servidor"
```

¿How can I do the same process with PHP code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Use [proc_open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

Comment: @AbraCadaver exec on windows calls cmd first then tries launching with it. Proc_open does direct execution on windows

Comment: if in same server use copy or exec to run a copy command, if between two servers use exec to run rsync